# Trying to get two LEDs blinking on a 3 V mains supply

Tags: led

I've installed two dummy security cameras. They use 2xAA to supply 3 V to a self-blinking LED.

I would like to wire them so that I don't need to bother with replacing batteries so I have purchased a 3 V DC 300 mA mains adaptor.

I've struggled by simply wiring them in parallel. First one installed and flashed fine. Second one appeared to have got burnt out. Ordered a replacement, but this won't flash on the 3 V mains adaptor (but will off battery.) In the process of trying to diagnose it appears I've burnt out the first LED now.

I'm thinking I need to start again, with a proper flashing LED circuit, but hopefully being driven from the 3 V mains supply I already have.

I've struggled to find clear instructions for something so simple. Can I just grab a couple of flashing 3 V LEDs and a suitable resistor, or do I need to go with static LEDs and a more complex circuit?

Comment: How would we know how to connect your unknown self-blinking LED? Part number of the LED? Link to datasheet? Anything? And did you use a resistor? Did you measure what voltage the DC adaptor outputs? Is it regulated or unregulated? Part number of the adaptor would help too.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I'm happy to start again with new LEDs and new circuit - would just keep 3v 300mA power adapter if possible. So given that looking for guidance :-)

Comment: [HERE](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/optoelectronics/led-indication-discrete/105?k=flashing+led&k=&pkeyword=flashing+led&sv=0&pv319=202627&sf=0&FV=-8%7C105&quantity=&ColumnSort=319&page=1&pageSize=25) are 6 flashing LEDS that operate on 3V DC (all variants of the same type). Yellow, green , red, ... . [Here](https://www.lumex.com/spec/SSL-LX5093BID.pdf) is the (not very good) datasheet of a red one.

Comment: @Ross, note that you haven't answered any of Justme's questions. Hit the [Edit] link below your question.

Comment: Is there any chance you've been connecting the LEDs the wrong way round?  They have + and - terminals.  A plain LED will handle small reverse voltages, but a self-flashing one might not.

Answer (score 1):

[HERE](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/optoelectronics/105?ColumnSort=319&FV=-8%7C105&page=1&pageSize=25&pv319=202627&quantity=&s=N4IgjCBcoKxaBjKAzAhgGwM4FMA0IB7KAbRAGYAWAdgA4yBOEAXXwAcAXKEAZXYCcAlgDsA5iAC%2B%2BMmEbQQSSGix5CJEACYADOoBs6qszadIPfsLHjJGtcnSpMAC3MACdNgAmIfM3FA&sf=0&sv=0) are 6 flashing LEDS that operate on 3V DC (all variants of the same type). Yellow, green , red, ... .
[Here](https://www.lumex.com/spec/SSL-LX5093BID.pdf) is the (not very good) datasheet of a red one.

Available in stock at Digikey.

Ensure the mains supplied 3VDC has a suitably large filter capacitor.

---

Here is a simple circuit that will flash standard LEDs.
IC1 is a hex schmitt trigger inverter.
To oscillate IC1 MUST have Schmitt trigger inputs (CD40106 [datasheet here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40106b.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1652859289113&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fcd40106b), 74HC14 [datasheet](https://www.nteinc.com/specs/7400to7499/pdf/nte74HC14.pdf),  ...)

IC1.1 is the oscillator.
R2 D1 (optional) shorten the low output period so IC1.3 / D2 has a short-on longer-off flash.  IC1.4/D3 has a long on / short off flash.
Mix and match as desired.
A single IC section can be used as a flasher allowing 6 per package if desired.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2far5Dr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>